# Quoting a replacement string for a regular expression

Tags: replace

Emacs Lisp has `regexp-quote` to quote any string to match it literally.  Apparently, there is no equivalent function to quote an arbitrary replacement string to use it literally.  I mean, what could I use instead of the imaginary `regexp-quote-replacement` in the following contrived[1] code?

```
(replace-regexp (regexp-quote "^$") (regexp-quote-replacement "\\&\\?"))
```

This code would be meant to replace a literal `^$` with a literal `\&\?`.

--

[1] I know that I could use `replace-string` in this case to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `search` and `replace` loop instead.

As the doc of [`replace-regexp`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/replace-regexp) indicates:

> This function is for interactive use only;
>   in Lisp code use `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` instead.

One of the advantages of this approach is that `replace-match` has a
`LITERAL` argument, which does what you're asking for.

```
(while (search-forward-regexp SOME-RX nil 'noerror)
  ;; This \\1 will be inserted literally as \1
  (replace-match " \\1" nil 'literal))
```

Comment: The question as posed says nothing about not wanting to use the function interactively. This does not really answer the question posed about `replace-regexp` at all.

Comment: @Drew (1) The question asks for something analogous to `regexp-quote` but which can be used for replacements. `regexp-quote` cannot be used interactively. (2) The example provided was not an interactive call, it was a piece of elisp code. 
(3) Given (1) and (2), it seems safer to assume the objective is elisp code. I'll be happy to retract if the author says otherwise.

Comment: I guess you're right. Funny that the OP was able to discover `regexp-quote` and learn about constructs such as `\&` in the `TO-STRING`, but apparently never noticed the several notes about the function not being intended for interactive use (the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Programming-Tips.html#Programming-Tips) is even clearer about that than the doc string).